# E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-ros-tutorials

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
following the ros tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem). 
When I run The pre-requisites command  $ sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-ros-tutorials, the following command is received on the terminal.

adil@adil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-tutorials
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Any suggestions on how to proceed from this.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252602/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-hydro-ros-tutorials/) by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Hydro is much too old and not available on 16.04. I recommend using Kinetic Kame instead.

Supported platforms are listed in [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-aug-2013)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2